# Hiding duplicate results from ListBox?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I use a Store Procedure to get the results and then I have a Datatable that fill in the results. From there the results are filled in a ListBox. I'm getting duplicate IDs and I want to remove the duplicate results.

```
private DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

ListBox1.DataSource = _dt;
ListBox1.DataValueField = "userId"; //column name in DT
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Joel's answer would work in your case. However, I'd probably try to avoid returning duplicates in the first place, by using `DISTINCT` in the stored procedure. This way, if you or somebody else needs the same data again, they don't have to filter out duplicates everywhere. Plus, you get the secondary benefit of not sending unnecessary data over the network between your database and web servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you use linq you can use:

```
var source = _dt.Distinct();

ListBox1.DataSource = source;
ListBox1.DataValueField = "userId";
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

**Edit:**
Ok, in researching a little more closely I've found that the `System.Data.DataRowCollection` does not implement the IEnumerable extension methods in the same manner as a typical IEnumerable such as `List`. In order to use the `Distinct()` extension method, you would need first to get the row set into a more basic IEnumerable.

```
IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow> rows = (IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>)_dt.Rows;
ListBox1.DataSource = rows.Distinct();
ListBox1.DataValueField = "userId";
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

While it works, it probably is not nearly as simple nor as efficient as the answer supplied by @Massimiliano.

Comment: For some reason .Distinct() isn't a class that's recognized in VS2010 even though I do have namespace using System.Linq; declared.

Comment: @nhat: Reviewing my code, my answer should actually be downvoted. I will provide an edit that should make my suggestion work, but it is not going to be the preferred method for this case. At best it can offer a learning guide for Linq and potentially serve as a wonderful bad example.

Comment: Thank you for your humble answer. That's most likely the reason for your 3 gold =)

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable distinctTable = originalTable.DefaultView.ToTable( /*distinct*/ true);
ListBox1.DataSource = distinctTable ;
ListBox1.DataValueField = "userId";
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx